# Is it possible to do some computation in the constructor function body other than Initialization list

Tags: c++

I know usually it's better to rely on the initialization list,

```
class A {
  public:
    std::vector<double> X;
    A(std::vector<double> &x ) : X(x) {/.../}
};

class B {
   public:
   A a1;
   A a2;
   B(std::vector<double> &x,std::vector<double> &y ) : a1(x),a2(y) {}
 }
```

Now it's possible to initialize some class B objects with

```
B b(vector_x, vector_y);
```

But if in the constructor of B, the initialization "A a2" requires some computation with vector_x and vector_y, then,

is it possible to do it in the constuctor function body?

or should I call some function in the initialization list?

```
class B {
       public:
       A a1;
       A a2;
       B(std::vector<double> &x,std::vector<double> &y ) : a1(x)
       {
        //do something like f(x,y), and initialize a2? how? 
       }
     }
```

What are the best ways to do something like this?

Comment: Any reason you can't do `B(std::vector<double> &x,std::vector<double> &y ) : a1(x), a2(f(x,y)) {}` provided that `f(x,y)` is stateless?

Comment: **Books** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list It is possible (have you tried it?) and sometimes necessary. However some feel it is best to do just the bare minimum to put an object into a legal state in the constructor and more complex stuff in member functions.

Comment: @Galik Why Books link?

Comment: @Component10  what did you mean by "f(x,y) is stateless"? perhaps you can post a snippet.

Comment: @PranitKothari Because OP doesn't seem to know if it is allowed to put logic into the body of the constructor or not. Any good book will discuss constructors.

Comment: @Galik the problem is 'A a2' is declared first, I really don't know how to intialize it in the constructor body? if not using initialization list

Comment: @lorniper: by _stateless_ I mean that `f(x,y)` will not rely on the state (values of variables etc.) of object that you are in the process of constructing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since class `A` doesn't have a default constructor, this example code will not compile:

```
B( std::vector<double>& x,std::vector<double>& y )
    : a1( x )
{
    //do something like f(x,y), and initialize a2? how? 
}
```

And if you can't redesign class `A` then you have to pass it an object in memory, where the expression is an lvalue.

However, since the reference to non-`const` passed to the `A` constructor is not retained, you can simply do

```
template< class Type >
auto temp_ref( Type&& o ) -> Type& { return o; }

B( std::vector<double>& x,std::vector<double>& y )
    : a1( x )
    , a2( temp_ref( std::vector<double>() ) )
{
    a2.X = f(x,y);
}
```

If you can instead fix class `A` then that's best, then you can do

```
class A
{
public:
    std::vector<double> x;
    A( std::vector<double> const& _x ) : x( _x ) {}
};

B( std::vector<double>& x,std::vector<double>& y )
    : a1( x )
    , a2( std::vector<double>() )
{
    a.x = f(x,y);
}
```

or even

```
class A
{
public:
    std::vector<double> x;
    A() {}
    A( std::vector<double> const& _x ) : x( _x ) {}
};

B( std::vector<double>& x,std::vector<double>& y )
    : a1( x )
    , a2()
{
    a2.x = f(x,y);
}
```

If `f` is a real function that you have available, or can practically make available, then you can now (after fixing `A`) also just do

```
class A
{
public:
    std::vector<double> x;
    //A() {}    -- Add if it is meaningful for the use of A.
    A( std::vector<double> const& _x ) : x( _x ) {}
};

B( std::vector<double>& x,std::vector<double>& y )
    : a1( x )
    , a2( f( x, y ) )
{}
```

placing that call in the initializer list.

Comment: @lorniper: I did indeed mean `a2`. Not sure about what you mean by didn't add `A(){}`, that's what I did? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @lorniper: Oh. I vary just one thing at a time, like in the scientific method. That makes it much easier to see the effect of each change. Adding a default constructor changes the use of class `A`, so it's a more drastic thing.

Comment: thanks ! , add default constructor so we can use a2() in the initialization list? btw, you use a2.'X' while you have 'x' in A

Comment: Fixed, thanks. Don't know where these typos are coming from. Keyboard devil grumble grumble…

Comment: thanks, if x is not a member of class A, then is it still possible to do something in the constructor body effectively as "a2.x = f(x,y)"?

Comment: @lorniper: you can always construct an `A` object after you have the vector you need, then assign that to `a2`.

Comment: yes, but then how do I initialize a2 in the body, I just found my base class have x only in the base constructor, and use some pointer to manipulate data,

Comment: @lorniper: you should post a **new question**, because the code you now describe sounds entirely different from the presented code.

Comment: thanks for the advice, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992395/how-to-get-the-initialisation-list-to-deal-with-objects-using-different-initiali

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can call a function in a constructor initialization list.

Assuming you can change the constructor of `A` to take a const reference you can write:

```
class A {
    std::vector<double> X;
  public:
    A(const std::vector<double>& x ) : X(x) { }
};

class B {
  A a1;
  A a2;
 public:
  B(const std::vector<double>& x, const std::vector<double>& y) : a1(x), a2(f(x,y)) { }
};
```

Comment: Note that with the OP's code this will only work if `f` returns a reference to non-`const`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'm assuming there is no good reason why `A` takes a _non-const_ reference. But good point.

Comment: thanks! what would be the difference for f? in case it's const or non-const reference?

Comment: @lorniper You can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference. I'm assuming `f()` returns by value so that would be a temporary and wouldn't compile with your `A` as it is.

Answer (score 0):

*But if in the constructor of B, the initialization "A b" requires some computation with vector_x and vector_y, then...*

That computation would be done after the initialization, not at the same time.

And, yes, you can do the computation inside the body of the B constructor. A constructor is a type of a function.

By the way, it would be a good idea to place your member variables under private scope.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pointer..

```
class B
{
  std::unique_ptr<A> a1;
  std::unique_ptr<A> a2;

public:

  B(vec x, vex y) : a1{new A{x}}
  {
    a2.reset(new A{f(x, y)}); // construct a2 with the result of f()
  }
}
```

This is assuming the function `f()` is a member of `B`...

Comment: What's the point of using pointer. Same could be done without one.

Comment: @doc No, it couldn't because `A` does not have a default constructor.

Comment: @ChrisDrew can't simply call `a2(f(x,y))` in initializer list?

Comment: @doc Yes, you can that but that is a different answer, my answer :) The point of using pointers though is to defer initialization until the body of the constructor. Agreed the example doesn't make that clear though.

Comment: @ChrisDrew you could also do `a2(new A(f(x, y)))` in initializer list, so I still don't see the point of this answer.

Comment: @doc, that implies that `f()` is a static function in `B` rather than a member of `B`, else, I'd imagine it's undefined behaviour!

Comment: @Nim §12.6.2 [class.base.init] 16 Member functions (including virtual member functions, 10.3) can be called for an object under construction...

Answer (score 0):

If A2 requires some computation with x and y then it's A2, which should provide adequate constructor

```
class A {
 public:
    std::vector<double> X;
    A(std::vector<double> &x) : X(x) {}
    A(std::vector<double> &x, std::vector<double> &y ) : X(x) {//do something with x, y}
};


class B {
    public:
     A a1;
     A a2;
     B(std::vector<double> &x,std::vector<double> &y ) : a1(x),a2(x, y){}
};
```

You could use private inheritance if you want to do something with x and y in initializer list of B, before `a1` and `a2` are initialized, but IMO it's not a sign of good design and it's pointless.

```
class F {
   public:
       F(std::vector<double> &x, std::vector<double> &y) {//f(x,y)}
};

class B : private F {
 public:
     A a1;
     A a2;
    B(std::vector<double> &x, std::vector<double> &y ) : F(x, y), a1(x), a2(y) {}
};
```

meh sorry for bugs...